# Getting "A default document is not configured " error when deploying ASP.NET MVC application on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

Developing an ASp.NET MVC 5 application. Runs without an issue on the development machine (Windows 7 x86). When I tried to deploy it on IIS 7.5 (Win Server 2008 R2 64 bit) I got 3 errors:

1. Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

I fixed this issue by removing targetFramework="4.5" from

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
```

2. The  tag contains an invalid value for the 'culture' attribute.

I don't know why but compliant was about the following entry:

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" culture="az-Latn" uiCulture="az-Latn" />
```

After removing culture="az-Latn" uiCulture="az-Latn" this problem also got solved. But I don't think this is a proper way of solving that, so it'd be good to know the right solution.

3. Now the third error is the one that's taken all my day. After solving the above two problems now I get the error in the image:

The best solution that seems to work for almost everybody is to add the following entry:

```
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

But I already have it in the config file. IIS was missing URLRewrite module so I installed it manually.(Don't know if this has anything to do with it though). Didn't help. Enabled 32 bit Applications. Didn't help. What else should I try?

[image]

Comment: In the app pool, what version of framework is set?

Comment: It's version 4.0.30319

Comment: Try to see if the physical path got all the permission

Comment: This is almost always caused because the app pool has the wrong framework set or perhaps you need to re-register (by running `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -i`)

Comment: I gave full control on wwroot to Everyone just for testing purposes but it does not help.

Comment: Also, just to be absolutely clear, the app pool you checked was for this web app and not default app pool?

Comment: @DavidG, for now re-registring ASPNET seems to have solved the probem because I get another error now. (It's complaining about Oracle.DataAccess) I'll let you know once I'm sure about that.

Comment: Great, I've put that as my answer. As for your Oracle error, make sure you have the Oracle client installed on the server :)

Comment: Thank's, that's what I'm doing now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible solutions

1. Make sure the application pool that is running your site is set to version 4. It's likely defaulted to v2 which will give you all the errors you mentioned in the question.
2. Re-register your framework with this command:

> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -i

I'd also revert those changes you have made (e.g. put the `targetFramework` attribute back in)